# Encountered SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"] while trying to plot a function

Tags: plotting, memory

I have an expression that simplifies to the following expression, which I denote as a function X.

```
X[\[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_] = 1/2 (2.87734/(r^2 (1 + r)) + (-1 + E^(-(2.87734/(r^2 (1+r))))) \[Beta] - (\[Alpha] ArcCot[0.120786 r^4 (1 + r)^2])/\[Pi]) + (0.99 (1 - (1.29037 r^6 (1 + r)^3 \[Alpha])/(48.2848 + 0.704439 r^8 (1 + r)^4)-E^(-(2.87734/(r^2 (1 + r)))) \[Beta]) (1 - (1.43867 Log[1 + r])/r))/(r (0.99 + r)) - (1 - (1.43867 Log[1 + r])/r) ((1.34538 r^8 (1 + r)^4 \[Alpha])/(48.2848 + 0.704439 r^8 (1 + r)^4) - (0.128035 r^16 (1 + r)^8 \[Alpha])/(236.223 + 6.89262 r^8 (1 + r)^4 + 0.0502791 r^16 (1 + r)^8) + (0.205369 r^5(1+r)^2 \[Alpha] (0.99 r (0.99 + r) + (1 + r) (1.37627 r (0.99 + 2 r) - 0.99 (2.97 + 5 r) Log[1 + r])))/((0.99 + r) (15.3695 + 0.22423 r^8 (1 + r)^4) (-0.688135 r + 0.99 Log[1 + r])) + 1/(2 r (0.99 + r) (1 + r) (0.688135 r - 0.99 Log[1 + r]))E^(-(2.87734/(r^2 (1 + r)))) (-0.99 r (0.99 + r) \[Beta] + (1 + r) \[Beta] (1.37627 r (-0.99 - 2 r + r (0.99 + r)) + 0.99 (2.97 + 5 r - 2 r (0.99 + r)) Log[1 + r]) -E^(2.87734/(r^2 (1 + r))) (-0.99 r (0.99 + r) + (1 + r) (-1.37627 r (0.99 + 2 r) + 0.99 (2.97 + 5 r) Log[1 + r]))))
```

When I try to plot this function with 'r' using the following

```
Plot[{X[0.10, 0.20], X[0.15, 0.20], X[0.20, 0.20]}, {r, 0, 10}]
```

I get `SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]`. However, I can obtain the plot by setting the lower limit to anything other than 0 (such as 0.001 etc.). Can anyone please point out why I cannot plot from 0 and how to avoid this issue? I am using Mathematica 10 on Windows 11.

Comment: Limit[[X[a,b],r->0] yield infinity.

Comment: The code as shown in the question produces the three curves without difficulty, although it does warn of underflows.  The comment by @Acus is correct but should not lead to memory allocation problems.